# .elf or .bin file to be download as application code in ARM cortex M4

Tags: arm, bootloader, cortex-m4

I am using a MCU with ARM Cortex M4 processor. 
I Have written a bootloader on it.
Using USB CDC ACM class, i am writting the application code in memory address 0x002000.
I have generated both .elf and .bin files of the application code which i want to run through this bootloader. 
Which file is required to be write in memory from bootloader?.elf or .bin?
I have generated both .elf and .bin.

Comment: Depends on the bootloader implementation. If you wrote it, you should know what it wants to be fed!  But, most typically, the .bin.

Comment: @pericynthion : Thank you for effort. Currently, in my bootloader, jumping to application code from boot code part is not implemented. For the same reason i want to know that which file is required to write in memory. If .elf is written in memory then how to run the application code from boot code? Similarly, if .bin file is written then how to run the application code? 
What steps should be required to follow in boot code?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer? I'm working on a similar problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bootloader is working fine.
I have used .bin file for downloading in flash.
to convert .elf to .bin file use the post building options for GNU gcc compiler as follow :
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O binary My_project.elf My_project.bin

It converts My_project.elf file to My_project.bin file.